# Allure report of tests aborted due to testing process failure: 'Test failed to run to completion.'

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, junit4, allure

I'm looking for a way to generate an allure report on tests that fail with the message: `Test failed to run to completion. Reason: 'Instrumentation run failed due to 'Process crashed.''.`
This message is reporting that a test did not complete successfully because the process being tested crashed during the test run.

I've created a listener that monitors test executions. However, in my opinion, this path is a dead end because the test doesn't fail during execution, it's not even scheduled to start.

I'm using

```
io.qameta.allure:allure-kotlin-junit4
io.qameta.allure:allure-kotlin-android
```